# My program will not print, closes immediately after entering a number (C)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int input, i, sum = 0;

    printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 5: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        sum += input + i;
    }

    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

When I open it up, it asks the question but as soon as I enter a number it closes without printing what the sum is.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, and, just a wild guess here, are you [running this on Windows from the Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505173/visual-studio-2010-program-closes-immediately-after-running) ?

Comment: Oh my mistake, what my question is, How do I get it to stop closing after entering what number I want before it gives me my sum. and Im using the newest version of visual studio community.

Comment: You will likely find the [**link in my prior comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505173/visual-studio-2010-program-closes-immediately-after-running) helpful if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl+F5 to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using TurboC compiler use getch();

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    //your code
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Or compiler is GCC - You can use following code to implement own getch(); and no need to include conio.h**
***here is the code for GCC***

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); //grab old terminal i/o settings
  new = old; //make new settings same as old settings
  new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; //disable buffered i/o
  new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; //set echo mode
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); //apply terminal io settings
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* 
Read 1 character without echo 
getch() function definition.
*/
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}
int main(){/*your statements*/ getch(); return 0}
```

**Reference**
***[gotoxy(), clrscr(), getch() and getche() functions for GCC Linux.](http://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/gotoxy-clrscr-getch-getche-for-gcc-linux.aspx)***